# Docker/Docksal: ERROR: for X Cannot start service X permission denied

Tags: docker, docksal

After running "fin init" I  get the following permission errors running docker and docksal and Mac 10.15.
This config previously worked but after a delete/reinstall I'm getting consistent errors.
It begins to run normally but has permissions issues when starting services.

```
Starting services...
WARNING: The green_bg variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The green variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The NC variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Creating network "sea" with the default driver
Creating volume "sa_cli_home" with default driver
Creating volume "sa_project_root" with local driver
Creating volume "sa_db_data" with default driver
Creating sa_pma_1 ... 
Creating sa_db_1  ... 
Creating sa_mail_1 ... error
Creating sa_cli_1  ... 

ERROR: for sa_mail_1  Cannot start service mail: error while mounting volume '/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/sa_project_root/_data': failed to mount localCreating sa_db_1   ... error
cca_project_root/_data, flags: 0xc00, data: addr=192.168.64.1,vers=3,nolock,noacl,nocto,actimeo=1: permission denied

ERROR: for sa_db_1  Cannot start service db: error while mounting volume '/mntCreating sea_pma_1  ... done
ume: mount :/Users/user/Sites/Sa:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/sa_project_root/_data, flags: 0xc00, data: addr=192.168.64.1,vers=3,nolock,noacl,noCreating sa_cli_1  ... error

ERROR: for sa_cli_1  Cannot start service cli: error while mounting volume '/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/sa_project_root/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount :/Users/user/Sites/SA:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/sa_project_root/_data, flags: 0xc00, data: addr=192.168.64.1,vers=3,nolock,noacl,nocto,actimeo=1: permission denied

ERROR: for mail  Cannot start service mail: error while mounting volume '/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/sa_project_root/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount :/Users/user/Sites/SA:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/sa_project_root/_data, flags: 0xc00, data: addr=192.168.64.1,vers=3,nolock,noacl,nocto,actimeo=1: permission denied

ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: error while mounting volume '/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/sa_project_root/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount :/Users/user/Sites/SA:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/sa_project_root/_data, flags: 0xc00, data: addr=192.168.64.1,vers=3,nolock,noacl,nocto,actimeo=1: permission denied

ERROR: for cli  Cannot start service cli: error while mounting volume '/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/sa_project_root/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount :/Users/user/Sites/SA:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/sa_project_root/_data, flags: 0xc00, data: addr=192.168.64.1,vers=3,nolock,noacl,nocto,actimeo=1: permission denied
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Comment: did you add the user to docker group?

Comment: Did you check the permissions of your project folder?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using [Docksal](http://docksal.io/) on macOS with NFS.

Searching the Docksal issue queue on Github, I find [this issue](https://github.com/docksal/docksal/issues/1275#issuecomment-588423883) to closely match your case.

Check `cat /etc/nfs.conf`. It should look like this:

```
#
# nfs.conf: the NFS configuration file
#
nfs.server.mount.require_resv_port = 0
```

From http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/nfs.conf/osx-10.6.php:

```
     nfs.server.mount.require_resv_port
              This option controls whether MOUNT requests are required to
              originate from a reserved port (port < 1024).  The default value
              is 1 (yes).  Many NFS server implementations require this
              because of the false belief that this requirement increases
              security.
```